# DAX select value based on condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm totally new to DAX so am trying to convert an easy SQL query to DAX to use with Powerbi.

What I'm trying to do is use a new measure to grab the DIR_D value from a SQL table table_1 that I've imported into powerbi, where DIR_VALUE = 2.

So I have a table table_1 that looks like this :

```
DIR_VALUE  DIR_D
1          0
2          102
3          254
```

So have tried a few options, am struggling with how to do this using DAX.

```
Measure 2 = filter('table_1'[DIR_D],'table_1'[DIR_VALUE] = "2")
```

Any help appreciated. Its got to be something simple....
Have looked at previous postes questions on SO already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This measure picks the unique `DIR_D` value when the corresponding value of `DIR_VALUE` is 2.

```
Measure 2 =
CALCULATE (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'table_1'[DIR_D] ),
    'table_1'[DIR_VALUE] = 2
)
```

If your real data does not have a unique value for `DIR_D` for distinct values of `DIR_VALUE`, then change out the `SELECTEDVALUE` aggregator with another appropriate aggregator function, e.g. `AVERAGE`, `MIN`, `MAX` or `SUM`.